# Calling static method from different class doesn't work without using default

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module

I've just finished a lengthy debugging session and while I solved the issue, I have no idea why my solution is necessary.

I have a file `Update.js` that looks like this:

```js
class Update {

  static doThisAfterClick = (event) => {
    console.log("First button clicked!");
  }

  static doThisWhenCalled = (name, age) => {
    console.log("My name is " + name + " and my age is " + age);
  }
}

export default Update;
```

In `Edit.js` I import the module:

```js
let Update = require('./Update');

class Edit {

  static fancyEventHandler = (event) => {
    Update.doThisWhenCalled("Peter", 42);
  }  

}
export default Edit;
```

and later, in `app.js` I add a few Event handlers:

```js
import Edit from "./Edit";
import Update from "./Update";

firstButton.addEventListener('click', Update.doThisAfterClick);

secondButton.addEventListener('click', Edit.fancyEventHandler);
```

Now the crazy part: Clicking *firstButton* logged `First button clicked!` as expected, but clicking *secondButton* gave an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Update.doThisWhenCalled is not a function.`.

I actually tried to debug this by inserting

```js
let x = Update.doThisWhenCalled;
debugger;
```

into `fancyEventHandler()` and saw that x was undefined.

Through some sheer luck I saw that I could use

```js
Update.default.doThisWhenCalled("Peter", 42);
```

instead and this resolved the issue. No idea why.

**What is wrong with calling the static method directly? And what is this "default" property?**

Comment: Why are you using `require()` instead of `import`?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] with the actual code of your files. Currently, neither *Update.js* nor *Edit.js* do `export` anything, the main module won't even load without errors.

Comment: @Barmar You spotted my mistake! I wrote the Edit-module before the Update-module and after my first readings about modules I was still under the impression that require() was preferable. Later on I changed my mind but forgot to update this particular line. That's why my IDE spotted no mistake either. Thank you!

Comment: @Bergi Sorry, I had forgotten to include that into the example. But it was there in my files, I just didn't copy it over. As you might imagine, my example was heavily simplified and was just a representation of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's related to the way you're exporting/importing, below is a possible fix:

**Update.js:**

```
class Update {
  static doThisAfterClick() {
    console.log("First button clicked!");
  }
  static doThisWhenCalled(name, age) {
    console.log("My name is " + name + " and my age is " + age);
  }
}

export default Update;
```

**Edit.js:**

```
import Update from "./Update";

class Edit {
  static fancyEventHandler() {
    Update.doThisWhenCalled("Peter", 42);
  }
}

export default Edit;
```

Comment: Thank you! It was the change from "let Update = require('./Update');" to "import Update from "./Update";" that made all the difference. I hadn't spotted that one and neither did my IDE.